# Can I grant a database user permission to create views in a schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to set up a security situation where my database user ("ApplicationUser") has permission to create, alter and drop views within a schema.

If I execute the statement

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: MySchema TO ApplicationUser;
```

And then connect to the database and execute the statement:

```
CREATE VIEW [MySchema].[MyView] AS SELECT * FROM SomeTable
```

I get the error message

```
CREATE VIEW permission denied in database 'MyDatabase'.
```

Is it possible to configure security the way I want, or must I grant "ALTER" on the whole database? Or something else?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
create schema myschema authorization ApplicationUser
GO

grant create view to ApplicationUser
GO
```

To do this you need to either change the authorization of the schema, which may have other consequences, or use something like a database DDL trigger.

For an existing schema do:

```
alter authorization on schema::myschema to ApplicationUser
```

Like I say, this way should be done with caution. For the other way http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: How does that differentiate between schemas?  Say if the op (or myself) wants to grant the create view permission to just one schema?  Do you grant the CREATE VIEW and then grant an additional permission on the schema?

Comment: muhmud, are you saying that schema-specific CREATE VIEW is not possible?  Need more info man.

Comment: Thanks for the update muhmud.  Sounds like I won't get exactly the security setup I'm after but this provides me with more info.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do this by...

1. Granting a create view/select permission on the database to a role
2. Grant alter permissions to that role for the schemas I want to have views
3. Deny alter permission to that role for the schemas I didn't want to have views

Here was my syntax...

```
USE [database];
CREATE ROLE [role];
GRANT SELECT TO [role];
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO [role];
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::[schema 1] TO [role];
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::[schema 2] TO [role];

--TEST 
/*
EXECUTE AS USER = '[user w/role]';
CREATE VIEW [schema 1].test AS (select 'test' as 'test');
DROP VIEW [schema 1].test
CREATE VIEW [schema 2].test AS (SELECT 'test' AS 'test');
DROP VIEW [schema 2].test 
REVERT
*/
```